# How do you create an non-trivial invariant from a symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, invariance

If you are given a symmetry, is there a way to find a non-trivial invariant of that symmetry? e.g. rotational invariance, $x\rightarrow Mx$  you would find the invariant $x^Tx$.

Or if you were given the symmetry of gauge invariance you might find the Maxwell Field invariant. Of coordinate invariance you might find one of the GR invariants.

Is there a general way to find at least one non-trivial invariant, given a symmetry?

And if not, is it provable that there is no general way?

Comment: Yes I know about Noether's theorem, but that just proves that for every symmetry there is a conserved quantity. Not sure it tells you how to make invariants???

Comment: Using Killing equation? (If you are talking about symmetry of the metric). It will gives us all the Killing fields for our symmetry transformation.

Comment: In general there may not be any nontrivial invariants. The "universal invariant" of the action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ is the projection $X \to X/G$ to the orbit space / quotient by the action, and it may consist of a single point. This means that every invariant is constant.